# Why does an HTML child element not seem to inherit the dir attribute when set to auto?

Tags: html, right-to-left, bidi, left-to-right

When I set the `dir` attribute to `auto` on a parent element, it does not appear that the child elements inherit `auto`, but it does appear that they inherit `ltr` or `rtl`.

According to [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir):

> In HTML the base direction is either (a) set explicitly by the nearest parent element that uses the dir attribute (which could be the html element), or, (b) in the absence of such an attribute, left-to-right (LTR).

And according to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-dir-attribute):

> If the element has a parent element and the dir attribute is not in a defined state (i.e. it is not present or has an invalid value)
> The directionality of the element is the same as the element's parent element's directionality.

If I understand that correctly, then every `<p>` should be inheriting its directionality from the parent `<div>` (in the last case below, `auto`), but it does not appear to be doing that when the directionality is set to `auto`. Why?

It appears this way in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, so it's not a browser issue.

```css
div {
        border: 1px red solid;
        margin: 1rem 0;
      }
p {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  }
```

```html
<!-- LTR -->
<div dir="ltr" id="div-ltr">
        <p>
          This div is set `ltr` so all of its descendants are `ltr` as well, no
          matter the characters directionality
        </p>
        <p id="english-ltr">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique,
          placeat
        </p>
        <p id="phoenician-ltr"> •  •  • </p>
      </div>
<!-- RTL -->
      <div dir="rtl" id="div-rtl">
        <p>
          This div is set `rtl` so all of its descendants are `rtl` as well, no
          matter the characters directionality
        </p>
        <p id="english-rtl">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique,
          placeat
        </p>
        <p id="phoenician-rtl"> •  •  • </p>
      </div>
<!-- AUTO -->
      <div dir="auto" id="div-auto">
        <p>
          This div is set `auto`, but the children all seem to default to `ltr`
        </p>
        <p id="english-auto">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique,
          placeat
        </p>
        <p id="phoenician-auto"> •  •  • </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the *direction* is inherited from the parent, not the value of the `dir` attribute.

Your div has no text nodes in it, so auto is treated as LTR.

Add some RTL text and it changes:

```html
      <div dir="auto" id="div-auto">    •  •  • 

        <p>
          This div is set `auto`, but the children all seem to default to `ltr`
        </p>
        <p id="english-auto">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique,
          placeat
        </p>
        <p id="phoenician-auto"> •  •  • </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, I was conflating `dir` with "directionality". But this also feels confusing — like, why would the child inherit is "directionality" from the parent's text but not the explicitly set `dir` attribute? Maybe I'm thinking too much like it's CSS. I guess I don't understand the reasoning